# CSS transition doesn't work with jQuery's .toggleClass()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When you click the link apply any CSS animation during show/hide toggle. The toggle works, but animation is not applied.

```js
$('.working-hours-link').click(function(e) {
  $(this).siblings(".hours").toggleClass('hidden shown');
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  -o-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
  display: none;
}

.shown {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  -o-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="working-hours-link" href="#">Show working hours</a>
<br>
<div class="hours hidden">
  Sunday: 12:00 pm-6:00 pm
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ako6uzxt/

Comment: which kind of transition are you expecting to see? color and background are actually fading, but the display property run like a switch. Maybe do you expect an opacity transition (from 0 to 1)?

Comment: `CSS` transitions doesn't work with `display` properties. Here are some [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-css-display-property) to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transitions on the CSS display property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-css-display-property)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`transition` doesn't work for `display`. try to change `display:none` and `display:block` to `opacity:0` and `opacity:1`

Comment: This leaves empty white space.

Comment: so try `max-height:0` and `max-height:150px` or whatever value is the maximum for your item heights

Comment: This works, but mouse cursor reacts to the hidden text (while at `opacity: 0;`) on hover.

Comment: because it overflow.. set `overflow:hidden`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because the `transition` CSS rule needs to exist on the element before the class is applied/removed from it. As such you can add that to the `.hours` rule. In addition you no longer need to use the vendor prefixes on `transition`.

Also note that you can't animate `display` so I used a combination of `opacity` and `height` instead.

```js
$('.working-hours-link').click(function(e) {
  $(this).siblings(".hours").toggleClass('hidden shown');
});
```

```css
.hours {
  transition: height, opacity 1s;
}

.hidden {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.shown {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  height: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="working-hours-link" href="#">Show working hours</a>
<br>
<div class="hours hidden">
  Sunday: 12:00 pm-6:00 pm
</div>
```

Comment: The toggled item is not going to be fixed height because of different amount of content for each sibling.

Comment: so just replace `height` with `max-height` and put the value of most availible tall item

Answer (score 0):

In css display: none and display: block the transition will not work. because the hidden file is not in html by default.. after click the button the files will show.. replace of display none we can use opacity:0; please remove the display: none and display:block

**css**

```
.hidden {
  opacity: 0; 
  visibility: hidden;
}
.shown {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility:visible;
}
```

Comment: @G-Cyr  yes ofcourse.. But in IE old version sometimes, visibility:hidden is must..

Comment: `visibility` leaves empty space.

Comment: In case ther e is an anchor tag inside the opacity:0 div.. Its not showing but the anchor tag click will work.. i mean the functionality will work.. so we can add visibility:hidden

Answer (score 0):

Please add this Code

```
.hours{display:none;background-color:#000;color:#fff;}

$('.working-hours-link').click(function(e) {
    $(this).siblings(".hours").toggleClass('hidden');
});
$('.working-hours-link').click(function(e) {
    $(this).siblings(".hours").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: This kind of works, but gets really clunky, show animation is fade while hide is slide.